# How do I access this hash's object's attributes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a hash with a Vehicle object and some Google Maps API calculations:

```
{#<Vehicle id: 9, type: "hybrid">=>#<GoogleDistanceMatrix::Route origin: #<GoogleDistanceMatrix::Place address: "LAX airport", extracted_attributes_from: {"address"=>"LAX airport"}>, destination: #<GoogleDistanceMatrix::Place address: "Venice Beach", extracted_attributes_from: {"address"=>"Venice Beach"}>, status: "ok", distance_text: "10.4 km", distance_in_meters: 10400, duration_text: "13 mins", duration_in_seconds: 780>}
```

How do I get the `Vehicle#type` and `GoogleDistanceMatrix#address` (LAX airport)? I can't seem to access it.

Comment: Where is that hash coming from? An external API? Do you use a specific gem?

Comment: it gets calculated in the project. it's not my project so I am not sure how this exactly happens @spickermann

Comment: try to call `.keys` method of that hash and share what will return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your hash has a `Vehicle` as a **key** and `GoogleDistanceMatrix::Route` as a **value** (note it's not a `GoogleDistanceMatrix` as you said), therefore you could access both with something like this:

```rb
my_hash.each do |key, val|
  puts key.type # => vehicle type
  puts val.origin.address # => explanation below on why #origin is needed
end
```

Also note that `GoogleDistanceMatrix::Route` does not contain an `address` property directly. Rather, `address` seems to be accessible by calling `origin` (which returns an object of type `GoogleDistanceMatrix::Place`) and then `address` on the result.